# Audio Source clip isn't changing in uity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

In Unity after using the walking sound effect the audio source clip changes to a walking sound effect. Though when I use the transformation sound effect the source clip doesn't change to the transformation clip.
Here is the code for transformation sound effect and walking sound effect

```
void Update(){//Walking
    if (!isMoving)
    {
        source.clip = walk;
        source.Play();
    }
    Animate();
    Transform();
}
void Animate()//Walking
{
    if(horizontal == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("run", false);
        isMoving = false;
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("run", true);
        isMoving = true;
    }

    if (horizontal < 0)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        right = true;
        left = false;
    }

    if (horizontal > 0)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        left = true;
        right = false;
    }
}
void Transform()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && hasTransformed)
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("retransform");
        decrease1 = true;
        timerToChange = 1.7f;
        hasTransformed = false;
        source.clip = transformation;
        source.Play();
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T) && !hasTransformed)
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("transform");
        decrease = true;
        timerToChange = 1.7f;
        hasTransformed = true;
        source.clip = transformation;
        source.Play();
    }
    if (decrease)
    {
        timerToChange -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (decrease1)
    {
        timerToChange -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if(timerToChange <= 0 && hasTransformed)
    {
        bodyParts.SetActive(false);
        bodyParts1.SetActive(false);
        bodyParts2.SetActive(false);
        robotCollider.isTrigger = true;
        hasTransformed = true;
        car.SetActive(true);
        carCollider.isTrigger = false;
    }
    if (timerToChange <= 0 && !hasTransformed)
    {
        bodyParts.SetActive(true);
        bodyParts1.SetActive(true);
        bodyParts2.SetActive(true);
        robotCollider.isTrigger = false;
        hasTransformed = false;
        car.SetActive(false);
        carCollider.isTrigger = true;
    }
}
```

All the variables have been assigned, so don't ask me if they are.

Comment: so other than if its not moving you set the walk clip and play it every frame ...how are your other 2 methods called?

Comment: They are called in the update function I just included the walk function because the actual update function is huge. I will add the transform function being called if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not that [`AudioSource.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html)

> If AudioSource.clip is set to the same clip that is playing then the clip will sound like it is **re-started**. AudioSource will assume any Play call will have a new audio clip to play.

Since you are calling `Play` each frame - under various conditions but still each frame - you ill almost never hear anything as the clip is always restarted.

---

Instead you might rather have some dedicated method doing a check like e.g.

```
private void SwitchToSound(AudioClip clip)
{
    // same clip already playing -> ignore to avoid re-start
    if(audioSource.clip == clip && audioSource.isPlaying) return;

    audioSource.clip = clip;
    audioSrouce.Play();
}
```

then you can use that everywhere you want to switch to a different clip.

---

As a second thing: You probably rather want to trigger those transformations **once** so you should rather use `GetKeyDown`.

Note that `GetKey` is true in **all** frames while the button stays pressed while `GetKeyDown` is only true in the very first frame i which the button is pressed.

---

Also I think you could simplify this quite a bit

```
void Transform()
{
    if((hasTransformed && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)
       ||(!hasTransformed && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)))
    {
        anim.SetTrigger(hasTransformed ? "retransform" : "transform");
        decrease = true;
        timerToChange = 1.7f;
        hasTransformed = !hasTransformed;
        SwitchToSound( transformation);
        source.Play();
    }

    if (decrease)
    {
        timerToChange -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(timerToChange <= 0)
        {
            decrease = false;
            bodyParts.SetActive(!hasTransformed);
            bodyParts1.SetActive(!hasTransformed);
            bodyParts2.SetActive(!hasTransformed);
            robotCollider.isTrigger = hasTransformed;
            car.SetActive(hasTransformed);
            carCollider.isTrigger = hasTransformed;
        }
    }
}
```